# CakePHP Data Validation 2 Input Fields

Tags: php, html, cakephp

```
    //View

    echo $this->Form->input('adult', array('options' => array('0'=>'0', '1'=>'1', '2'=>'2', '3'=>'3', '4'=>'4'), 'default' => '0'));
    echo $this->Form->input('concession', array('options' => array('0'=>'0', '1'=>'1', '2'=>'2', '3'=>'3', '4'=>'4'), 'default' => '0'));

    //Model

    ...
```

The problem I am having is that, I know how to code validations for individual fields BUT here I want to compare 'adult' and 'concession' fields together and give an error if the SUM of them is less than '1'.

Any advice here would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom validation rule on your model, something like this;

```
function atLeastOneSelected($data)
{
    if (empty($this->data[$this->alias]['adult']) && empty($this->data[$this->alias]['concession'])) {
        // both fields are empty
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and in your validation array;

```
public $validate = array(
    'adult' => 'atLeastOneSelected',
    'concession' => 'atLeastOneSelected',
);
```

Comment: Glad I could help! You may need to check if my example works in all situations (e.g. when saving other fields in your model without updating these fields), but based on this example, I think you'll be able to create a proper validation-rule

Comment: yeah it worked really well, i just tweaked it to show a custom error message but the core of it worked amazing. thanks!!!

Comment: Good luck on your project! Oh, I made a small modification to my example; I was using `$this->name` but changed it to `$this->alias` so that it will also work if you're attaching the model using an alias :)